# Alternative way to register or activate Windows 8

Tags: windows-activation

I am having issues entering the product code in a newly installed Windows 8 workstation. It does not allow me to enter the product code in the activation centre, it just gives this omitted random code, still claiming Windows is not activated. So fact is all UI experiences runs from terminal commands, therefore I was wondering if there is a possible way to register Windows 8 through command prompt?

*Note: I did try to register online, no success. Complains about some sort of DNS problem. Point is I do not want to register online, what would be the point of giving out product keys then?

Comment: I can only elaborate by adding I have the product code, I don't want to spend time filling out online forms after time spend to actually get activation centre connected. I do a lot of setups everyday, so time is valueable. Regarding the screenshot - I already activated it before I could take one, I will upload it as soon as I have a new PC with Windows 8, should be very soon.

Comment: If you do post a screenshot of the error be sure to removed the license information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Run the `command prompt` as an administrator

2.Enter `slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` where `xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` is your product key.

Then try activating again.
I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I had similar issues and did like this to solve it. :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cmd` indirect to register your windows per phone. :-)

1. Start  `cmd`
2. write `slui4`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. A window opens.
5. Choose your country and click Next.
6. Now you have the telephone-number which you can call to activate windows 8.

Comment: Problem here was I received an error, after the cmd was entered, a Wordpad window opened and displayed "Cannot find this file. Please verify the correct path and name are given."